# Can we add legend for function "text" to matlab?

Tags: matlab, legend

I want to add legend for my plot. Because I want to use the marker plot 'heartsuit', I use the 'text' function. If I add legend function in my code, it can't work. The command window say that 'Warning: Plot empty.' So, can we add legend to 'text' function? I have searched in many source, and I cannot find it.

```
clear all;
clc;
m = '\heartsuit';
x = 0:pi/5:2*pi;
y = sin(x);    
text(x,y,m,'fontname','Arial','color','red','FontSize',18,'HorizontalAlignment','center','VerticalAlignment','middle');
grid on;
xlim([min(x) max(x)])    
ylim([min(y) max(y)])
legend('Solusi Numerik');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a hack. Plot a fake `NaN` point, create a legend for it, hide its legend line, and add the heart-suit in the string with appropriate space at an appropriate position. Adjust the color of heart-suit and/or string if needed.

```
hold on;
LgdStr = 'Solusi Numerik';        %Your legend string
hNaN = plot(NaN,NaN);             %Plotting nothing
[~, icons] = legend(hNaN, LgdStr);%Creating a legend to get required space for string
icons(2).Visible = 'off';         %Hiding the fake legend line
icons(1).Position(1) = 0.125;     %Adjusting the starting position of text
icons(1).String = ['\color{red}', m, '   \color{black}',LgdStr];
%Last line includes red-colored heart-suit at reasonable space from black-colored text
```

**Result:**

[image]